# Add second class to html with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to add a second class to a list item in jQuery. It seems as though the class is being added but the styling is not being applied. If I add the second class inline however, it works as expected.

### HTML

```
<div id="container">
  <ul id="myList">
    <li>First</li>
    <li>Second</li>
    <li class="firstClass">Third</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#container #myList .firstClass.addedClass {
  color:red;
}
```

### jQuery

```
$("#container #test li:last-child").addClass('addedClass');
```

Comment: Please post your code here and your example has no element with the id `#test`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your html doesn't have an element with an id of `test` that contains `<li>`'s.

```
<div id="container">
    <ul id="myList">
      <li>First</li>
      <li class="firstClass">Second</li>
      <li>Third</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

You selector should be changed to:

```
  $("#container #myList li:last-child").addClass('addedClass');
```

Or in a simpler form (since you are keying off id's):

```
$("#myList").find("li:last-child").addClass('addedClass');
```

Also your css should be:

```
#myList .addedClass {
  color:red;
}
```

Since your `last-child` element does not have a class of `firstClass` nor a parent of `#test`

Also if your intent is just to target the last element in the list to affect the display you could just do this with css using:

```
#myList :last-child {
  color:green;
}
```

Comment: Your answer helped me get to the correct solution. My JSBin was not updated properly for some reason. The first class and the added class should have been on the same element. I updated the question appropriately. Thank you!